# xslt template only returns a single row

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

I have a xml file that is automatically created by another system that I need to pull data out of and join to another set of data. The nodes are recursive and I've tried using the template/apply template of the xsl transform but I always end up with only a single line rather than all the lines.

Here is a sample xml output:

```
<rdBookmarks>
  <Folders>
    <Folder Name="My Items" ID="">
      <Folder ID="a04593ac-41d5-44b4-a895-d4b6abe29984" Name="Student Summary" SaveTime="2014-10-21T11:08:41-04:00" />
      <Folder ID="4ef6e607-710d-4c52-abf7-de7377e33bd6" Name="Student Detail" SaveTime="2014-10-21T11:17:51-04:00" />
    </Folder>
  </Folders>
</rdBookmarks>
```

Here is my latest attempt at the xsl transform:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <rdData>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </rdData>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Folder">
    <Folder>
        <xsl:attribute name="ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="Folder/@ID" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Folder">
            <xsl:value-of select="Folder/@Name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </Folder>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

My current output is in the correct format, but it's only returning a single line and I can't figure out why.

```
<rdData>
    <Folder ID="a04593ac-41d5-44b4-a895-d4b6abe29984" Folder="Student Summary"/>
</rdData>
```

I found the answer at [XSLT templates and recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835567/xslt-templates-and-recursion) extremely helpful but it doesn't quite answer why I'm not getting multiple lines.

Comment: You need an <xsl:apply-templates /> inside your folder template if you wish to pick up the child items

Comment: What is the logic that you follow here? Why do you want to output the two folders, but not the third one? Are you only interested in folders that do not have child folders? Or something else?

Comment: I'm interested in all the folders, not just the two, so in my example it would ideally output 3 rows, "My Items", "Student Summary", and "Student Detail"

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested in all the folders, not just the two, so in my example
>   it would ideally output 3 rows

Then I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <rdData>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </rdData>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Folder">
    <Folder>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@ID | @Name"/>
   </Folder>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Applied to your input example, the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdData>
   <Folder Name="My Items" ID=""/>
   <Folder ID="a04593ac-41d5-44b4-a895-d4b6abe29984" Name="Student Summary"/>
   <Folder ID="4ef6e607-710d-4c52-abf7-de7377e33bd6" Name="Student Detail"/>
</rdData>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template is producing just one row because that row is the result of transforming the outer `<Folder>` element (Folders/Folder) not the inner ones (Folders/Folder/Folder), and there is only one outer one.

Replacing your second template with the following should produce one `<Folder>` in the transformation for each inner `<Folder>` element, but I cannot be sure that the resulting stylesheet will transform all other inputs as you want.

```
<xsl:template match="Folder/Folder">
  <Folder>
    <xsl:attribute name="ID">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ID" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Folder">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </Folder>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who commented, your replies helped me find the solution. The reason I was only getting one of the sub folders rather than the main folder or both sub folders was because I was referencing the parent and calling the attributes of the child. I fixed the issue by removing the "Folder/" from the selects and adding in the "xsl:apply-templates" at the end. This goes through the parents and applies the same template to the children so that all folders are listed.

```
<xsl:template match="Folder">
    <Folder>
        <xsl:attribute name="ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="@ID" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Folder">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </Folder>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```